# Wrap io.PipeReader to store progress

Tags: go, pipe

I would like to keep track of the progress in an `io.Pipe`. I came up with the following struct `ProgressPipeReader` which wraps `io.PipeReader`, storing the progress in bytes inside `ProgressPipeReader.progress`:

```
type ProgressPipeReader struct {
        io.PipeReader
        progress int64
}

func (pr *ProgressPipeReader) Read(data []byte) (int, error) {
        n, err := pr.PipeReader.Read(data)

        if err == nil {
                pr.progress += int64(n)
        }

        return n, err
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to use it to wrap an `io.PipeReader`. The following snippet

```
pr, pw := io.Pipe()
pr = &ProgressPipeReader{PipeReader: pr}
```

yields the error

```
cannot use pr (type *io.PipeReader) as type io.PipeReader in field value
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error describes, you are trying to store a `*io.PipeReader` value in a `io.PipeReader` field. You can fix this by updating your struct definition to the correct type:

```
type ProgressPipeReader struct {
        *io.PipeReader
        progress int64
}
```